# facebook permission not updating

Tags: php, facebook, permissions

i am developing a facebook application for my website.i have updated the permission and saved.but the changes i have made is not updating.it showing "Changes saved. Note that your changes may take several minutes to propagate to all servers." when i save changes.but i am getting the old permission while i testing 1 hour after making changes.the "Preview Login Dialog" shows another settings

[image]

the above image shows the permission page while testing

[image]

this image is the login privew
and given permissions are as shown below

[image]
all images are showing different permissions.what will be the problem.

Comment: You might have to delete the app form your app center. (That worked for me)

Comment: Basic permissions are added by default (you can't disable those) so don't pay attention to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly advise you not to use Authenticated Referrals since facebook announced that they're going to stop using it on February 6th, 2013. Instead specify the permissions via JS SDK or PHP SDK.

Answer (score -1):

Thanx for Saber Kordestanchi

The changes that  made is updating in a while but the actual problem is not here,there is a possibility of showing undesired permissions.That is additionally i specified permission via PHP SDK,so fb showing this permissions.so i added required permission in the code

```
$params = array('scope' =>'email,friends_photos,publish_stream,photo_upload',
                          'redirect_uri' => 'http://abcd.in/in.php');
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```